# How to multiply different indices in a row in Pandas DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[produce.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5rJS.png)

> Im trying to create a function called **get_total_produce** that takes a column value from **'Name'** and multiplies the values of **'Fruit' & 'Vegetables'** in that row to return the total number of produce. How can I do do this with Pandas?

> Current Code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('Produce.xlsx'))
```

> Input for desired output

```
get_total_produce('Kroger')
```

> Desired Output

```
280
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the code below with [**`pandas.Series.mul`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) :

```
def get_total_produce(name):
    fruits_val = df[df['Name'] == name]['Fruits']
    vegetables_val = df[df['Name'] == name]['Vegetables']
    result = fruits_val.mul(vegetables_val).iloc[0]
    return result
```

Or with [**`pandas.DataFrame.prod`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) :

```
def get_total_produce(name):
    filt_df = df.loc[df['Name'] == name, ['Fruits', 'Vegetables']]
    result = filt_df.prod(axis=1).iloc[0]
    return result
```

##### # Output :

```
get_total_produce('Kroger')
280
```